# javascript to split string by first of length

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this `"1a8abder412183a2b9654123879"`

How can I split the string by length of first char like this using javascript

```
1 -> a,
8 -> abder412,
3 -> a2b,
9 -> 654123879,
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: First char of what? Why is `3` chosen right after `abder412`? What about the missing `1 -> 8`? Please share your attempts and explain what didn’t work.

Comment: What happened to 18 before 3a2b? Can there only be one digit before a letter that decide the length?

Comment: are you sure about the result?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only length of 1 to 9, then you could get the length from the actual index and slice the array by taking the index plus expected length. Proceed until no more string si left.

```js
var string = '1a8abder412183a2b9654123879',
    result = [],
    index = 0,
    length;

while (index < string.length)
    result.push([length = +string[index++], string.slice(index, index += length)]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You have an additional `[1, "8"]` though.

Comment: i know. but maybe is is a key/value data set and the first counts.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = '1a8abder412183a2b9654123879';
let keys = [1, 8, 3, 9];

let splitByKeys = (input, keys) => {
  let lastIndex = input.indexOf(keys[0]);
  let splits = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= keys.length; i++) {
    let index = i < keys.length ? 
      input.indexOf(keys[i], lastIndex) : 
      input.length;    
    let m = input.substring(lastIndex + 1, index);
    lastIndex = index;
    splits.push([keys[i - 1], m]);
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(splits);
}

let output = splitByKeys(input, keys);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = "1a8abder412183a2b9654123879";
const chunks = (arr, acc = []) => {
  return (arr.length === 0) 
    ? acc
    : chunks(
      arr.slice(parseInt(arr[0])+1), 
      [...acc, arr.slice(0, parseInt(arr[0]) + 1).join('')]
    ); 
}
console.log(chunks([...str]));
```